# Auferonyms - Words Inside Words

Tags: word, word-property, letters, password

I have hidden something from my nemesis Aufero inside other words. The rules are that I can only add one or more letters to a word inside that word (not at the beginning or end), I can only add a single string of letters, and both words must be valid.

For example, I can turn *actuate* into *accentuate*, but I cannot turn *scribe* into *describe*, or *mount* into *monument*. Word pairs such as actuate-accentuate are called **auferonyms**.

---

I have taken the letters of the the secret word and hidden them inside the following words. Aufero only knows that my secret has something to do with an upcoming wedding.

```
transverse    ruin       taint     better

patient    convalesce    wraith    found
```

What am I hiding from Aufero?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are hiding is the

> Invitations

Reasoning

> Looking at the auferonyms and the letters that need to be removed we have
>  TRA**NS**VERSE $\rightarrow$ TRAVERSE
>  RU**I**N $\rightarrow$ RUN
>  T**A**INT $\rightarrow$ TINT
>  BE**TT**ER $\rightarrow$ BEER
>  PAT**I**ENT $\rightarrow$ PATENT
>  CO**NV**ALESCE $\rightarrow$ COALESCE
>  WRA**I**TH $\rightarrow$ WRATH
>  F**O**UND $\rightarrow$ FUND
>  The removed letters are **NSIATTINVIO** which anagrams to **INVITATIONS**.

Comment: Just beat me to it!! :P

Comment: Blimey, that was fast! I should probably make the next one harder :) Great job and +1.